# How to make a button so that when you click on it, a block with a darkened photo pops up

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

How to make a button so that when you click on it, a block with a darkened photo pops up

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

to do something like this, I would create the darkened photo first with hidden display. After clicking the button make display visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<dialog>` element containing the darkened photo. Attach an event handler to the button that when clicked opens the modal using `HTMLDialogElement.showModal()` method.